# Understanding fiddler statistics

Tags: wcf, http, fiddler

We are sending a HTTP WCF request to a 3rd party system hosted on our servers and were experiencing a significant delay between sending the request and getting the response. The 3rd party are claiming that they complete their work in a few seconds but in fiddler I can see a significant gap between the `ServerBeginResponse` and the `GotResponseHeaders`.

Now I'm not sure what could account for this delay? Could someone explain what the `ServerBeginResponse`and the `GotResponseHeaders` timers in Fiddler actually mean?

[image: Fiddler statistics tab screenshot]

Comment: Greetings, I am having an issue that seems strikingly similar, but I can't nail down what is causing the delay. Were you able to solve this or determine the cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timers mean pretty much exactly what they say-- The **ServerGotRequest** timer is set when Fiddler is done transmitting the HTTP request to the server. The **GotResponseHeaders** timer is set when Fiddler has read the complete set of response headers from the server.

In your screenshot, there's a huge delay between **ServerBeginResponse** (which is set when the first byte of the server's response is returned) and **GotResponseHeaders** which suggests that the server spent a significant amount of time in completing the return of the HTTP response headers.

If you send me (via Help > Send Feedback) a SAZ capture of this traffic, I can take a closer look at it.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for you help on this. I've sent the saz. It could simply be that the service is taking a very long time to return. I just want to eliminate all other possibilities before I start pointing fingers!

Comment: @Liam - What was the result of this? Does the long gap mean it was taking the 3rd party a long time to complete or an issue on the server processing the header? We are encountering a similar problem.

Comment: @Belogix, for us, the issue ended up being HTTP throughput. The connections were queuing on the server and we couldn't get them though fast enough. We've since increased the number of servers and improved our load balancing reducing this issue. Hope that helps

Comment: @Liam - Great, thank you and for the VERY fast reply on an older thread! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Eric, I am also facing a similar situation where according to my understanding request is reaching the server but the time shown in GotResponseHeaders is almost 6 minutes later. ClientConnected: 22:34:40.246
ClientBeginRequest: 22:34:41.338
GotRequestHeaders: 22:34:41.338
ClientDoneRequest: 22:34:41.697
DNS Lookup:   0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 0ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 22:34:40.246
FiddlerBeginRequest: 22:34:41.697
ServerGotRequest: 22:34:41.697
ServerBeginResponse: 22:34:41.697
GotResponseHeaders: 22:41:20.745
ServerDoneResponse: 22:41:20.745

Comment: Hi Eric, Please also suggest how can I share the SAZ file to you?

Comment: Email link in the header of https://ericlawrence.com/