# SOAP API access error from a website hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-8

I have an application hosted in IIS in Windows Server 2012. At regular intervals the website looses its capacity to call a secure SOAP Api used in the application. The issue is resolved by restarting the Website in the IIS. But I cannot restart the application at all points of time.

I am receiving the following error message in the event viewer and the 
Application error log.

Event Viewer

> The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 80.

Application Error Log

> “Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'URL' ”

Windows Update has not installed the known S Channel SSL Update KB from Microsoft which is known to generate this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742938/how-to-solve-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-chan

Answer (score 0):

If you look for cause of Error:

Alert code 80 in TLS protocol means:

> **Internal Error:** An internal error unrelated to the peer or the
>   correctness of the protocol makes it impossible to continue, such as a
>   memory allocation failure. The error is not related to protocol. This
>   message is always fatal.

Seems something is not good in configuration of SOAP UI, what cases might be there are:

1. **Memory consumption in Service:** Checkout [WCF - Random client timeout when making multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991398/wcf-random-client-timeout-when-making-multiple-calls)
2. **Something related to *Throttling***(upper limit of service call & optimisations) setting : You need to set maximum concurrent call for any hosted apllication. Make sure that value is greater than required connections. Checkout [WCF timeout exception detailed investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981475/wcf-timeout-exception-detailed-investigation)
3. **Something wrong with server** (Memory leak in application, Less memory, other processes): Monitor Server logs in Eventviewer for Errors in application.
4. **Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool** :Any managed application hosted on IIS uses application pool & application pool has Idle time-out. This means if for a certain period(Idle time-out for AppPool) no hosted application on that AppPool is used AppPool is recycled to free up resources. New calls after that need to Bring up AppPool that require more time than Usual than can result in timeout for some application if its timeout is less.
   Check out [**Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: The application starts re functioning after restarting the IIS. The URL is accessible in iexplorer without any certificate validation checks. The API Calls are processed successfully using SOAPUI even during the time when the error is being raised.

Comment: Make sure you enforce `https` for the hosted application on IIS, without that certificate is never used.