# Delay between ServerBeginResponse and GotResponseHeaders

Tags: java, http, server, fiddler, fiddler-dev

I have been hitting my head against this but couldn't find a suitable article for the same.

```
ClientConnected:        08:18:40.592
ClientBeginRequest:     08:18:40.616
GotRequestHeaders:      08:18:40.617
ClientDoneRequest:      08:18:40.967
Determine Gateway:      0ms
DNS Lookup:             0ms
TCP/IP Connect:         0ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:        08:18:40.604
FiddlerBeginRequest:    08:18:40.967
ServerGotRequest:       08:18:40.967
ServerBeginResponse:    08:18:40.970
GotResponseHeaders:     08:19:31.248
ServerDoneResponse:     08:19:31.248
ClientBeginResponse:    08:19:31.248
ClientDoneResponse:     08:19:31.248
```

there is a 1 min delay between **GotResponseHeaders** and **ServerBeginResponse** . Please help me understand what can be the reason behind it.

Note: I already went through the post [Understanding fiddler statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872999/understanding-fiddler-statistics) but no success.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your question. It took 1 minute for the server to calculate the response. That is unusual but there is nothing to understand about it especially if you don't tell us what type of server (what services it offers) and what request you sent to it.

Comment: I have saved the Fiddler session , but not sure how to attach the same here. Can you guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Previous question was answered by EricLaw who is actual creator of Fiddler tool, so his answer gives everything you are looking for. You can calculate the time to first byte with the help of ServerGotRequest and  ServerBeginResponse.

•   ServerGotRequest - Exact time that Fiddler finished (re)sending the HTTP request to the server.

• ServerBeginResponse - Exact time that Fiddler got the first bytes of the server's HTTP response.

Time to first byte = ServerBeginResponse – ServerGotRequest.

Time to first byte depends on multiple factors. I have faced similar issue due to poor internet connection at home. for additional information related to time to first byte refer https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/16081-time-to-first-byte-seo.html

Comment: This issue here isn't delay in getting first byte in response, but delay in "ServerBeginResponse" and "GotResponseHeaders"

Comment: GotResponseHeaders - timer is set when Fiddler has read the complete set of response headers from the server.

Comment: Thanks, But my concern is the reason of delay between "ServerBeginResponse" and "GotResponseHeaders"